Update trigger in PLpgsql
I am totally new to sql. Please, can anybody help me to create a trigger to PostgreSQL database.
So i have 1 table named "tables" with 2 columns named "w" (games won, integer) and "gp" (games played, integer). So the plot is auto-update trigger of "gp" value depending on modifying "w" value.
Table looks like this:
club       |  gp | w   |
Juventus| 2   | 2   |
Lazio      | 2   | 2   |
I need to create an update trigger which will update "gp" column like gp+1 after adding 1 won game to column "w" like w+1. What it would be?
I've tried something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_gp_increment()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.w = OLD.w+1 THEN
        UPDATE tables SET NEW.gp = OLD.gp+1;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER gp_increment
BEFORE UPDATE OF w ON tables
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION n_gp_increment();

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I think i am going wrong way and it seems to me that i don't understand some basics about triggers. Will be grateful for any help with this. Thanks for your attention.

Just read the documentation, that will help far better.

What happens if they lose? That is a game played.

Thanks for attention. If they loose there will be the same function.

Step 1: Create the Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_gp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Check if the w (games won) column is being incremented
    IF NEW.w > OLD.w THEN
        -- Increment the gp (games played) column by the same amount
        NEW.gp := OLD.gp + (NEW.w - OLD.w);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Step 2: Create the Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER update_gp_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF w ON tables
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.w IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.w)
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_gp();

Explanation:
Function update_gp(): This function checks if the w column has increased. If it has, it updates the gp column accordingly.
Trigger update_gp_trigger: This trigger calls the function before any update to the w column. The WHEN clause ensures that the trigger only fires if the value of w has actually changed.
UPDATE tables
SET w = w + 1
WHERE club = 'Juventus';


Thank you very much, it works. I'll try to implement your solution on other columns too!
